# Can a variational inequality (necessary condition for minima) be strict?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, gateaux-derivative

A well-known fact in optimization theory is the following:

> Let $C_{ad}$ be a non-empty, convex subspace of a real Banach space $B$ and let $F: U \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on an open set $U$ containing $C_{ad}$. If $F$ is Gateaux differentiable (or at least has all directional derivatives) in $U$ and $\overline{u} \in C_{ad}$ is such that
>   $$ \overline{u} = \operatorname{argmin}_{u \in C_{ad}} F(u),   $$
>   then
>   $$ F'(\overline{u})(u - \overline{u}) \ge 0 \qquad \forall u \in C_{ad}. $$

I have some troubles deeply understanding the so-called *variational inequality*, in particular I cannot find an easy but significant example in which such inequality is strict (at least for some $u$).

For instance, if $B=\mathbb{R}^n$ all (existing) directional derivatives must obviously vanish. Is this something related to finite/infinite dimension?

I will be grateful if someone could provide such an example and perhaps an insight on that famous variational inequality.

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting the following example. Take the first quadrant as $C_{ad}$, i.e., $x \geq 0$, and $y \geq 0$. Take for objective function $F(x,y) = (x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2$. The minimum is reached at $(0,1)$. At this point the gradient is $(2,0)$. Any direction at the minimum can be written as $(x, y-1)$. The scalar product between these two vectors $2x > 0$ for $x >0.$

So this is not related to finite/infinite dimension.

Comment: Interesting example, thank you. On the other hand, I think here we are heavily exploiting the fact that $(0,1)$ lies on the boundary of $C_{ad}$.

Comment: Correct, say, if you take $C_{ad} = B$, then you will get $F'(\overline{u})(u - \overline{u}) = 0.$ In other words, if you are allowed to move in any direction, you cannot improve the objective

Comment: I am trying to figure out whether or not this still occurs in infinite dimension; or if we can find an example of a functional exhibiting a minimum at an interior point, for which the inequality holds in a strict sense.

Comment: The answer is no. You can choose $u = \overline{u} + t(v-\overline{u} )$. If $\overline{u}$ is in the interior of $C_{ad}$, then for small enough $t$, $u \in C_{ad}$  and we get $tF'(\overline{u})(v - \overline{u}) \geq 0$, which implies $F'(\overline{u})(v - \overline{u}) =0.$ Intuitively, if moving into one direction allows the objective function to increase, then moving in the opposite direction will decrease the objective function, unless this is not an admissible direction, i.e., a constraint prevents it

Comment: I do not agree: the first variation need not to be linear if only the existence of directional derivatives is postulated (see statement in the question)...